# Travis CI push to github failed

Tags: git, github, travis-ci

I have a push command to GitHub in my `.travis.yml` file and I'm getting the following error:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'repoUrl'
```

travis file:

```
language: node_js
cache:
  directories:
    - ~/.npm
notifications:
  email: false
node_js:
  - '9'
after_success:
  - npm run release && git push --follow-tags origin master && npm publish
branches:
  except:
    - /^v\d+\.\d+\.\d+$/
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try using a `valid` username and password? :)

Comment: Where I define the username and password?